How to Put the Title EXPAND on the expand arrow in v-data-table expandable
<v-data-table
        v-if="userRoleId != 3"
        class="DepartmentTable dataTableExpensionTable"
        :items="missedRecords"
        :search="search"
        :headers="userHeaders"
        item-value="id" 
        id="table-to-export"
        show-expand
        dense
      >
      
        <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item }">
          <td :colspan="columns.length">
            <v-data-table-virtual
              class="subDataTables"
              :headers="timeStudyHeadersTransplantSub"
              :items="item.userTaskList"
              hide-default-footer
            >
            </v-data-table-virtual>
          </td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>

I want to show the title of the expandable content next to the expandable arrow in a v-data-table. Specifically, I would like the expandable arrow in the header to include a title or label indicating what will be expanded when the arrow is clicked. This title should dynamically reflect the content that will be shown upon expansion.

timeStudyHeadersTransplant: [
{
title: 'expand',
value: 'data-table-expand'
},
],

You can use the item.data-table-expand slot (docs here):
 <template v-slot:item.data-table-expand="{ item, internalItem, isExpanded, toggleExpand  }">
      <div>
        <VBtn
          :icon="isExpanded(internalItem) ? '$expand' : '$collapse'"
          size="small"
          variant="text"
          @click="toggleExpand(internalItem)"
        ></VBtn>
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
   </template>

